# MVC Razor radiobuttons using jQuery and multiple hiddenfields with same name

Tags: jquery, razor, radio-button, hidden-field, radio-group

The code below works, but I can not distinguish a way to retrieve the correct hiddenfield in order to pass the correct radio button values.  There are multiple hiddenfields with the same name and jQuery will grab the first radioAccessId.

Any suggestions on how I can get the assigned hiddenfield per listaccesshold span?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="list-unstyled margin-top-10 margin-bottom-10">
        @For Each access As AccessLevel In Model.AssignedAccessLevels
        If access.AccessLevelId <> 0 Then
        @
        <span class="listaccessholder-@access.AccessLevelId">
            <li>
                <div class="input-group">
                    @access.AccessLevelName
                    <div class="icheck-inline">
                        @code
                        If access.AccessFlag = "Yes" Then
                        @<label>
                            <input checked type="radio" name="AccessFlag-@access.AccessLevelId" value="Yes" group="AccessFlag-@access.AccessLevelId"> Yes
                        </label>
                        @<label>
                            <input type="radio" name="AccessFlag-@access.AccessLevelId" value="No" group="AccessFlag-@access.AccessLevelId"> No
                        </label>
                        Else
                        @<label>
                            <input type="radio" name="AccessFlag-@access.AccessLevelId" value="Yes" group="AccessFlag-@access.AccessLevelId"> Yes
                        </label>
                        @<label>
                            <input checked type="radio" name="AccessFlag-@access.AccessLevelId" value="No" group="AccessFlag-@access.AccessLevelId"> No
                        </label>
                        End If
                        End Code
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="radioAccessId" value="@access.AccessLevelId" />
                </div>
            </li>
        </span>
        End If
        Next
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Razor will generate:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="list-unstyled margin-top-10 margin-bottom-10">
        <span class="listaccessholder-353">
            <li>
                <div class="input-group">
                    Epi
                    <div class="icheck-inline">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="AccessFlag-353" value="Yes" group="AccessFlag-353"> Yes
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input checked type="radio" name="AccessFlag-353" value="No" group="AccessFlag-353"> No
                        </label>

                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="radioAccessId" value="353" />
                </div>
            </li>
        </span>
        <span class="listaccessholder-388">
            <li>
                <div class="input-group">
                    System Administrator
                    <div class="icheck-inline">
                        <label>
                            <input checked type="radio" name="AccessFlag-388" value="Yes" group="AccessFlag-388"> Yes
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="AccessFlag-388" value="No" group="AccessFlag-388"> No
                        </label>

                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="radioAccessId" value="388" />
                </div>
            </li>
        </span>
        <span class="listaccessholder-392">
            <li>
                <div class="input-group">
                    Site Administrator
                    <div class="icheck-inline">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="AccessFlag-392" value="Yes" group="AccessFlag-392"> Yes
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input checked type="radio" name="AccessFlag-392" value="No" group="AccessFlag-392"> No
                        </label>

                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="radioAccessId" value="392" />
                </div>
            </li>
        </span>
        <input type="hidden" id="radioviewId" value="6" />
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**   My goal was to get the section with YES/NO and pass the value, but i can't get the section without the accessId.  Each accessId is saved within a hiddenfield and has the same name.

```
$(function () {
// Someone has clicked one of the access radio buttons
var accessId = $(this).find('#radioAccessId').val();
var listaccessholder = 'span.listaccessholder-' + accessId;
var radioViewId = $(this).find('#viewId').val();
$(listaccessholder).click(function () {
    var accessFlag = "";
    $(this).find('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function () {
        accessFlag = $(this).val();
    });
    // Make a viewModel instance
    var viewModel = new Object();
    viewModel.viewId = radioViewId;
    viewModel.AccessId = accessId;
    viewModel.AccessFlag = accessFlag;

    //Ajax call to post the viewModel to the controller
    var strung = JSON.stringify(viewModel);

    $.ajax({
        url: app_base + 'Menu/UpdateAccess',
        type: 'POST',
        data: strung,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            ShowUserMessage("Access updated");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            ShowUserMessage("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
        }
    });
  })
});
```

**I would like to move forward with this approach, but I need some advice on how from SOF community.**

**Controller**

```
<HttpPost>
    Public Sub UpdateAccess(viewModel As AjaxAccessViewModel)
        If Request.IsAjaxRequest() Then
            Dim status As New Boolean
            Try
                status = _menuService.UpdateAccessFlag(viewModel.ViewId, viewModel.AccessId, viewModel.AccessFlag, GetUserInfo.UserID)
            Catch ex As Exception
                'TempData("message") = New GenericMessage() With
                '    {.Message = "Update failed.",
                '     .MessageType = GenericMessages.danger}
            End Try
            If (status = True) Then
                'TempData("message") = New GenericMessage() With
                '    {.Message = "Successfully updated the access flag.",
                '     .MessageType = GenericMessages.success}
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to just put your view ID and access ID as attributes of the radio input. This way you don't have to worry about selecting values from different levels.

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    var o = {};
    o.viewId = $(this).data("viewid");
    o.accessId = $(this).data("accessid");
    o.accessFlag = $(this).val();
    alert(JSON.stringify(o));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="list-unstyled margin-top-10 margin-bottom-10">
        <span class="listaccessholder-353">
            <li>
                <div class="input-group">
                    Epi
                    <div class="icheck-inline">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio"  value="Yes" data-accessid="353" data-viewid="6"> Yes
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input checked type="radio" value="No" data-accessid="353" data-viewid="6"> No
                        </label>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </span>
        <span class="listaccessholder-388">
            <li>
                <div class="input-group">
                    System Administrator
                    <div class="icheck-inline">
                        <label>
                            <input checked type="radio" value="Yes"  data-accessid="392" data-viewid="6"> Yes
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio"  value="No" data-accessid="388" data-viewid="6"> No
                        </label>

                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </li>
        </span>
        <span class="listaccessholder-392">
            <li>
                <div class="input-group">
                    Site Administrator
                    <div class="icheck-inline">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" value="Yes"  data-accessid="392" data-viewid="6"> Yes
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input checked type="radio" value="No"  data-accessid="392" data-viewid="6"> No
                        </label>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </span>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Simple and elegant answer that relieved me from my logical deadlock.  Thanks noriMonsta